# Android: databasehandler return null

Tags: android, sql, database, android-intent

i have this method in my database class as shown below:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUser() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + user;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("userid", cursor.getString(3));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return user;
}
```

and in my homeActivity I am able to fetch the value as shown below:

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            HashMap<String, String> userdetails = db.getUser();
            String name = userdetails.get("name");
            userID = userdetails.get("userid");
            username.setText(userID + " " + name );
```

and when a continue button is clicked, it will go to the next activity and i want to pass the userid value to the next activity

```
 buttonContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent afterhome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                SecondActivity.class);
                        afterhome.putExtra("userid", userid);

                        startActivity(afterhome);
                    }
                    });
```

However, the value i got from the secondActivity is always 0.

my second Activity codes are as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
         Intent intent = getIntent();
    userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");

}
```

Why is that so? Please advice. Thank you

Comment: `the value i got from the secondActivity is always 0.` you are talking about which value?

Comment: @donfuxx the value is userid